# Searching for capital letters in string using regular expressions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am attempting to locate 3, 4, or 5 consecutive capital letters within a string. They can proceed a '$' or '(' but this is optional. Below is what I have that handles the capital letters but I haven't figure out how to check for letters proceeding a '$' or '('.

ex: ($ABC), (ABC), $ABC, ABC     <---all should trigger

```
searches = [r'[A-Z]{5}', r'[A-Z]{4}', r'[A-Z]{3}']
correct = '$ABCD'

        for search in searches:
            confirmed = re.search(search, correct)
            if confirmed:
                return confirmed
            else:
                return False

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I don't see how the character preceding the sequence of capitals would matter. Post your code, the input, the output and the expected output.

Comment: You can simplify with `r'[A-Z]{3,5}'`.

Comment: Sci Prog thanks for the answer, that fixed it.

Comment: You dont need regex to do. Function is enough to do

Comment: Try this regular expression,`searches = r'[(]?[$]?[A-Z]{3,5}[)]?'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `regex` is overkill here, just use plain Python.

```
>>> correct = '$ABCD'
>>> any(correct[i:i+3].isupper() for i in range(0,len(correct)-3,3))
True
>>> correct = "AbCD"
>>> any(correct[i:i+3].isupper() for i in range(0,len(correct)-3,3))
False
```